# Prevent JavaMail from decoding base-64 content passed as java.lang.String object

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Some messages are received from the JavaMail API in getContent() as a java.lang.String object. If the content encoding is base-64, I would like to see the String as the original base-64 string and not as an already decoded String.

Whenever I use

```
Object msgContent = message.getContent();
```

for the object java.lang.String, the base-64 content is already converted. In my application, I should transmit the message in its original body format.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you get when you use the `DataHandler` object direct via the `getDataHandler()` method? There are methods like `getInputStream()` or `getDataSource()`. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MimeBodyPart.getRawInputStream](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getRawInputStream--) method.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.